# Read a single file in HDF5 container with Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I'm trying to read a single file from a HDF5 container I previously wrote. I though this is straightforward: Derive index from filesize and fileindex and read the corresponding part of the HDF5 file.

```
file = h5read(filename, datasetname, ...
         [ones(1, length(dataSize)-1) fileIdx], [dataSize(1:end-1) fileIdx]);
```

This translates to `h5read('myfile.h5', '/data', [1 1 1 4] , [1024 1024 4 4]);`in the following example:

```
% info for myfile.h5
h5disp('myfile.h5');

% HDF5 myfile.h5.h5 
% Group '/' 
% Dataset 'data' 
%     Size:  1024x1024x4x5
%     MaxSize:  1024x1024x4x5
%     Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
%     ChunkSize:  1024x1024x4x1
%     Filters:  deflate(1)
%     FillValue:  0.000000

% read in myfile.h5:
h5read('myfile.h5', '/data', [1 1 1 4] , [1024 1024 4 4]);
```

... and works great for the first three tiles, but throws an error for the fourth tile:

```
Error using h5readc
The index arguments exceed the size of the dataset.

Error in h5read (line 58)
[data,var_class] = h5readc(Filename,Dataset,start,count,stride);
...
```

However, the previous `h5disp('myfile.h5');` indicates, that the HDF5 container is as big as 5 of those files (`1024x1024x4x5`) which I am using with

```
info = h5info(filename, datasetname); 
dataSize = info.Dataspace.Size;
```

HDF5 container is fine. Reading all files and then accessing the BLOB in Matlab before worked fine.

```
data = h5read(filename, datasetname);
file = data(:,:,:,fileIndex);
```

And as I said, my method works for the first three tiles, but then fails. Am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look over `doc h5read` again. You seem to be misunderstanding the `start` and `count` parameters.

`start` is where you start reading data from, `count` is how much data to read. When you request `h5read('myfile.h5', '/data', [1 1 1 4] , [1024 1024 4 4]);` you are asking to start at the beginning of the 4th tile (`[1 1 1 4]`), then read 4 full tiles (`[1024 1024 4 4]`). As the dataset only has 5 tiles, this gives you your size exceeded error.

To read the 4th tile only try `h5read('myfile.h5', '/data', [1 1 1 4] , [1024 1024 4 1]);`